# UPS Reference Tracking in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use my Excel spreadsheet, which I use to keep track of my UPS shipments. I had used the format of: which worked great, but i'd like to do it with a reference as well. 
http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum=[TRK_ID]&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16
Where [TRK_ID] would reference the cell range of reference numbers instead of tracking numbers. With this I could click on the link in the cell and be taken to a page with the PO reference tracking information.

Comment: Which formula(s) are you using currently? I'm not sure what you mean by "[TRK_ID] would reference the cell range of reference numbers instead of tracking numbers."

Comment: The formula i'm using is:        =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1z",AH2)),HYPERLINK("http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum="&AU2&"&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16", "UPS Tracking page"),"")                                                                                                                I'd like for a similar function to be done, where the PO reference number is uploaded to the UPS tracking site instead of the actual tracking number

Answer (score 1):

Excel actually has a formula for this...

```
=HYPERLINK(link address, friendly name)
```

so, something like

```
=hyperlink("http:....&tracknum="&A1&"...rest of url","Track this package")
```

should get you where you want to get to

Comment: @Paris Meltzer In order for the hyperlink function to work, note that the link has to be valid and that, `http://` or `https://` is required

Comment: I'd like for the formula to be something link this so that it grabs the PO number and inserts it into the tracking site with a reference option instead of actual tracking number      =HYPERLINK("http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum="&M2&"&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=25&track.y=16", "UPS Tracking page") ------------Where M2 is the po reference number

Comment: once you know how the URL is formed with a tracking number embedded, you can use the `=HYPERLINK(` and form the URL with `"&M2&"` replacing the part of the URL that has the tracking number/refence number/however you are referring to the packages